# File encoding latin character in Java

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1, file-encodings

I have a template file (template.txt) saved in utf-8 format. Contents are as below:

```
placholder1¬placholder2
```

Notice that it has a latin character **¬** .

My Java application reads this file replaces the placeholder as per business logic and saves it to another file (cdr.txt) which is also in utf-8

Contents of cdr.txt are as below:

```
val1Â¬val2
```

This file is then transferred to remote system via FTP and in remote system when I see the content it looks like:

```
val1ÂÂ¬val2
```

I want this file content to be:

```
val1¬val2
```

Where am I going wrong?

My java application is running with option -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Comment: Make sure you're handling all strings as UTF-8, both when reading and writing content to/from the files mentioned. If you do, then there should be no problem. Show us some code from when you read / write the files

Comment: Also, make sure you're compiling with UTF-8 as encoding if you have the latin character somewhere in the java sourcecode.

Comment: Character encoding problems can be in many places. Make sure that whatever program you are displaying the content of the file with, is interpreting it as UTF-8. Otherwise the file might be correct, but it's just being displayed incorrectly.